# Signed App Won't Post on FB

Tags: android, facebook-sharer, android-facebook

My app shares okay before it was signed. Now that it was signed, it won't share. But I can get profile details so I know that it is connected. Is it because of the pending publish_action review? But I am registered as an admin. Thanks guys.

Comment: did you generate the key-hash using your keystore which you use to sign you apk and put that keystore at facebook app settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have added keyhash for your app package name in the developer console and enabled Sandbox mode.

For posting you require to take `publish_action` permission and also as per new rules of Facebook, you need to get a approval from Facebook in order to do tasks like manage pages, Publish etc.

You can do this by going to `Status & Review` section of your app.There in the `Submit Items for Approval` section, you can start a submission.

[image]

In the screenshot you can see initially we have only `email`, `public_profile` and `user_friends` permissions. You can click on `Start a Submission` to see the list of item which needs approval to use it and select the required items and  start submitting your app. According to Facebook, it may take 5-7 business days to get the approval.

Reference 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

Comment: yeah, that probably is the answer, review is still pending. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ site, in `Settings`, you will see `Key Hashes`, add the signed keystore's Key Hashes